# In Palantir Reports: How can I see number viewers for more than 30 days?

Tags: palantir-foundry

The Report can display number viewers, or number of views in 30 days. I need a solution so that I can find more stats on how many times a given Report has been viewed(updated) each day and for as long as the report exist.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how multiple configuration options of your stack are set, as well as how data retention is configured. Meaning that this is unlikely to be supported as you expect. If this is business critical please reach out internally through your support channel.

Comment: Thank you @fmst. The Report is used for visualize data from Contour analysis, and I just wont know how many times the report has been viewed.